# Rails Tutorial — 9.3.3 Current_User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

So I'm following the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book), and I've gotten to the portion where we want to sign a user in with a sign_in SessionHelper.

**Question 1**:

```
  module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user) #set current_user
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user #get current_user
    @current_user
  end
```

What I'm having difficulty with is the part that reads:

> The problem is that it utterly fails to solve our problem: with the code the user's signin status would be forgotten: as soon as the user went to another page.

I don't understand how this is true? I read on and understand the added code makes sure @current_user is never nil. But I'm not seeing how current_user would revert to nil if we just established it in 5th line.

**Question 2**:

The updated code reads as such:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user) #in helper because used in view & controller
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user) #set current_user
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user #get current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token #<-- short-circuit evaluation
  end

  private

    def user_from_remember_token
      User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token) #*=use [] instead of 2 vars
    end

    def remember_token
      cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
    end
end
```

In the remember_token helper, why does it use cookies.signed[] instead of cookies.permanent.signed[] & why doesn't it use ||= operator we just learned about?

**Question 3**:

Why do we need to authenticate_with_salt? If I authenticate & sign_in can see the id & salt attributes from the user who was passed to it, why do we need to double_check it? What kind of situation would trigger a mixup?

Comment: You should really break this up into separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that instance variables like `@current_user` are only set for the duration of the request. The controller and view handler instances are created specifically for rendering once and once only.

It is often easy to presume that because you've set a variable somewhere that it will continue to work at some point in the future, but this is not the case. To preserve something between requests you need to store it somewhere, and the most convenient place is the `session` facility.

What's missing in this example is something along the lines of:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

Generally it's a good idea to use the write accessor to map out the functionality of the `sign_in` method you've given as an example:

```
def current_user=(user)
  cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  @current_user = user
end
```

It's odd that there is a specific "sign in" method when the act of assigning the current user should be the same thing by implication.

From a matter of style, though, it might be more meaningful to call these methods `session_user` as opposed to `current_user` for those situations when one user is viewing another. "Current" can mean "user I am currently viewing" or "user I am currently logged in as" depending on your perspective, which causes confusion. "Session" is more specific.

**Update:**

In response to your addendum, the reason for using `cookies` to read and `cookies.permanent` to assign is much the same as using `flash.now` to assign, and `flash` to read. The `.permanent` and `.now` parts are intended to be used when exercising the assignment operator.

Comment: Tadman, thank you so much. I think I understand 95%. Which is the Session facility where the session_user is being stashed that you mention?

Comment: The `session` method available to both the controller and the view encapsulates this functionality. The sessions themselves can be stored in a number of ways, but the default is a special kind of cookie. Other options include the filesystem and the database.

Comment: Thanks again for your answers. I added a third question sometime after you answered my first two. I realize now I should've broken this up into 3 questions. But any chance you know the answer?

Comment: Generally you should ask three questions if you have three questions. `authenticate_with_salt` is simply a method for resolving a user by the "secret" salt, which I consider a bad idea since that sort of information is not supposed to be shared with anyone, even in encrypted form. A special-purpose authentication token is a better idea.