# Where are instance variables in a Rails helper module stored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

A tutorial I am following has in the subdirectory `app/helpers` the below SessionsHelper module which is used by many controllers and views. But where is the instance variable `current_user` stored when it is first created? What is the class of the object where it is stored?

When a controller first invokes the `current_user` method the `current_user` instance variable is created. When a view then invokes the `current_user` method how is it that a `current_user` instance variable is already present? Is `self` set to the controller object during the rendering of the view?

```
module SessionsHelper
  ...
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: i think you can follow this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575188/rails-tutorial-9-3-3-current-user

Answer (score 4):

This answer tells in general about how instance variables are passed between controller and view: [How are Rails instance variables passed to views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855178/how-are-rails-instance-variables-passed-to-views)

So basically, if @current_user is set by a controller, that instance variable (along with all others) will be passed from your controller context on to the view context. If it has not been set by a controller, it will be set the first time a view uses it.

For more information, see the other answer. It is a good read.

> Pasted from @mechanicalfish answer:

```
def view_assigns
  hash = {}
  variables  = instance_variables
  variables -= protected_instance_variables
  variables -= DEFAULT_PROTECTED_INSTANCE_VARIABLES
  variables.each { |name| hash[name[1..-1]] = instance_variable_get(name) }
  hash
end
```

Passing them to the view (github):

```
def view_context
  view_context_class.new(view_renderer, view_assigns, self)
end
```

Setting them in the view (github):

```
def assign(new_assigns) # :nodoc:
  @_assigns = new_assigns.each { |key, value| instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) }
end
```

Comment: So during helper call inside a view, self is a `view_context_class`? What kind of class is it actually? Thanks.

Comment: Its an  `ActionView::Base` i guess:   https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c5552a3dd28e35cce64462765cc41c5355db0f1/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb#L49-L67

Comment: A helper is a module, which, while being similar to a class, is not similar to an object. The difference is that a module is mixed in where it is included. To put it a bit simply, this is the equivalent of copy-pasting the module code in. So, since the helper code is pasted in to the view, self is a view_context_class