# Rails: Issue with if statement using ajax and jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am posting new "tweets" and with jquery and ajax I am able to show the newly posted tweet without refreshing the page. But in my view template, I have an `if statement` that checks if it is the `current_user` and if so, displays the delete button.

But Ajax does not read the `if statement` and does not display the delete button. The delete button shows up if I refresh the page or if I remove the if statement. That defeats the purpose since the button shows up on other users' profiles also.

Here is my view:

```
<ul class="tweets>
<li>
    <span><%= tweet.content %></span><br>
    <% if current_user?(@user)%>
        <%= link_to "Delete" tweet, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <%end%>
</li>
</ul>
```

My create.js.erb: `$('.tweets').prepend('<%= j render(@tweet)%>')`

Comment: do you really expect the ajax request to reread your original view?, unless you're showing the tweet partial?

Comment: In your partial, try debugging current_user and see if its actually being sent.  Just at the end of your content block put a "ID: #{current_user.id}" or something along those lines to see the output.

Comment: If it does read current_user, then perhaps the if statement is executing to false?  Which is strange due to the fact that it works on reload.  Perhaps try using a different if syntax? (this is just a random guess / couldn't hurt to try kinda thing).  Maybe try "if current_user.id == tweet.user.id" ?

Comment: @apneadiving, thanks for your insightful input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `current_user` is the user object for the current logged in user, and you have a user associated with your tweet.  To verify ownership, I would recommend:

```
    <% if current_user.id == tweet.user.id %>
```

**Edited:**

Doing the above will require rails to perform an addition database query to obtain the `tweet.user` user data.  Changing it to the following will eliminate the additional query:

```
    <% if current_user.id == tweet.user_id %>
```

Comment: I guess its doing an extra query to get the user data for `tweet.user`.  Perhaps doing `if current_user.id == tweet.user_id` will save that extra query.

Comment: This is what I was trying to get at, nice job Michael.  It's been a while since I have even looked at Ruby :)

Answer (score 1):

Not at a computer, but try: `if current_user == @user`

Comment: So if you're setting `@user = current_user` in the controller and then checking `if current_user == @user` wouldn't that always return true?

Comment: If you're using `=` instead of `==` then this isn't the answer (you may want to create your own answer and select that).  I was curious if `current_user` was supposed to be compared to `@user`, not sure if it would work if they're both `null`.  I think I was more questioning whether the conditional is doing what you think it is `current_user`.

Comment: I think this answer may help explain `current_user`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575188/rails-tutorial-9-3-3-current-user

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `current_user` to some instance variable on your controller action:

```
@current = current_user
```

I believe you don't have access to this variable there, but you do have access to all instance variables you set up before returning the response from the controller.